# Unlock different Apps from lock screen

Tags: lock-screens

I just got the Galaxy S6 and am new to Android.  Is there any way to have the phone open a different app/program, depending on how I swipe open the lock screen?

I.e. if I go up, right, up - open Music.  If I go left, down, left, open Chrome, etc.

Comment: Is there a problem in adding shortcuts on the Lock Screen?

Comment: @Firelord - how do you add shortcuts (Google didn't really help)? I'd like to keep my lock screen as "clean" as possible, so instead of having a bunch of icons on it (would that be a shortcut?), I'd rather choose to launch apps via predetermined swipe pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've mentioned below some use-cases tested on Android 5.0.2. Choose the one which suits your need.

## [GMD GestureControl](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goodmooddroid.gesturecontrol)

It needs root access. It can launch an action (say music app) using gesture from any app opened on the screen including lock-screen.

#### Usage instructions

1. Install and launch the app.
2. Tap Menu key and select **Settings**. Choose **Device Setup** at the very end of instructions if the gesture doesn't work.
3. Enable **Start on boot** to get rid of the need of launching this app manually to activate gestures on lock-screen or system-wide.
4. Create a gesture by tapping **Select Gesture**.
5. Choose which type of gesture you want, be it curvy (select **Record Gestures**) or the simple straight directional ones.
6. Unless you chose **Record Gestures**, the step would be to tap the direction icons to record gesture.
7. - **Touch Point**: Mention the  number of touch or fingers you would be using to make the gesture
   - **Anywhere**: Location on screen where the gesture would work
   - **Action**: Choose the action to be performed like launch of an app, once you're done making the gesture
   - **Per App Action**: Mention where do you want your gesture to be activated. Default is everywhere

   Go to **Action**.
8. Choose **Application** if you want an app to be launched.
9. Choose your app.
10. Go to **Advanced options**.
11. Enable **Activate on Lock Screen**.
12. Save and apply the changes.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge; hover to know details)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

I tried this app with CM12's default screen lock and third-party [SlideLock Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidelock). The result is that the gesture would execute the action if you perform the gesture on lock-screen but you can't see anything unless you unlock the screen if Password/PIN/Pattern or any security measure is set.

*Nevertheless, it is a very powerful, intuitive and useful app.*

## [GestureLocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gettingsignals.android.GestureLocker)

It doesn't need root access. Last updated in 2013, yet surprisingly, it worked on my device without hitches. Also, it seems that unlike traditional lock-screens it simply creates an overlay on the screen (with a lock icon) and your opened app  would continue to be visible but non-interactive unless you perform the unlock or other user defined gesture.

#### Usage Instructions

1. Install and launch the app, and uncheck **Show LockScreen Gesture** (it hints your gesture on lock-screen).
2. Uncheck default gestures and tap **Add Gesture**.
3. Name and record your gesture, then tap the newly created entry.
4. Select the app which you want to be launched using the gesture.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge; hover to know details)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

---

## Notable mentions

1. [Gestos - Gestures](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imaxinacion.gestos) -- last update an year ago, so it didn't work satisfactorily on Lollipop. But it may work nicely on Kitkat or prior Android versions.
2. [Pi Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pilockerstable) -- it is a regularly updated lock-screen app and has some inbuilt gestures with no support to add user gestures as of now. I noticed some glitches during usage but that may be device specific.
3. [Locker Master- Fun, DIY Themes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qiigame.flocker.global) -- you can create your own custom lock-screen without any programming I believe. It required internet connection to work satisfactorily and I dropped this idea considering its hunger for app permissions.

---

I've compiled two videos (ripped) to show the two main apps in action, both of size ~6MB:

- [GMD GestureControl](https://goo.gl/5xsri3)
- [GestureLocker](https://goo.gl/8Im0XD)

Cheers!

Comment: Oh wow, that's great! Thanks, I'll start looking through these!