# Enable software menu without virtual keys

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, buttons, accessibility

I have a broken touch screen at the bottom of my Jiayu G45 (Android 4.2.2) phone. Thus the capacitive buttons are not available any more. I've found a program (Soft Buttons) which enables software menu in apps but as a side effect it occupies a part of the screen at the bottom and renders virtual buttons there (back, home etc.). Those buttons don't work for me and I don't want to dedicate a part of screen for them. So I wonder whether it is possible to enable the software menu without virtual buttons?

I have root access.

Soft Buttons does almost what I need. When "enable virtual keys" option is selected it sets two properties in `/system/build.props`

```
# added by Soft Buttons
qemu.hw.mainkeys=0
ro.show.navigationbar=yes
```

and asks to reboot. What I expected that setting

```
qemu.hw.mainkeys=0
ro.show.navigationbar=no
```

will do exactly what I need. But it looks like the second prop value is just ignored in case first one is set to 0, as navigation bar is still shown.

Here is a screenshot (just an example, not a screenshot from my phone)

(Click the image to enlarge).

[image: IMG:]

Comment: do you have root access ?

Comment: @Firelord that comment should be an answer

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf I'm done, thanks, but after reading the question again, why do I feel like I misinterpreted the question? Do you see a mismatch in the question and my answers too?

Comment: @Firelord no I see no mismatch the OP asked for enabling software menu without virtual buttons as he said an I quote "I don't want to dedicate a part of screen for them" so the gestures is the best way to go ,all though there is a possibility that the OP is asking to activate (show) the tree dots button on apps

Comment: Thanks, and I'm sure now the answers should suffice. They can be extended to a full scale replacement for all navigation buttons.

Comment: For that navigation part still being shown, see if this answer can be of any help to you: [Enable On-screen navigation in CM12 (Lollipop) using shell?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/113413)

Comment: can you please tell us what it is exactly that you are looking for ? do you want to force the three dot menu button without navigation bar  ?

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf, please take a look at uploaded screenshot.

Comment: oops, sorry, it looks like it will appear just after my accounts merging, here is a link to the image http://i.stack.imgur.com/j3DfF.png

Comment: Please refer [help center](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts.

Comment: @gumkins i saw the new edit and I posted a new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the OP made his question more clear ,I have a more simple solution since he doesn't need a navigation bar he just want the virtual menu called **The three dots button**

**requirements** :

1. Xposer installer get it from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-installer-versions-changelog-t2714053) (JB/KK only ) for Lollipop or Marshmallow it's [over here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811)
2. 3dot Mod xposed module get it from [here](http://repo.xposed.info/module/it.tnx.xposednavbarmod)

**Procedure :**

1. Install the module on you phone ,activate it under Xposed installer >> modules ,reboot the phone when activating it for the first time
2. it's Done the nav bar will disappear and the 3dot button will always show up.

Comment: This solution looks interesting. My main concern is current Xposer code state: Experimental (high risk of bugs). Also, I have to do  (but first to learn how to) a full system backup before installing it. Honestly, I didn't think this requires such dances with a tambourine.

Comment: I use xposed on my phones all the time it is a must have and a more safe solution to mod any Android phone

Comment: Yes, certainly I should (and now have to) try it. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't install Xposed framework as it reports about a known issue with my ROM http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=52289793&postcount=5

Answer (score 3):

### [LMT Launcher](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1330150)

**Requires root access.**

I won't go into the details, but know that it doesn't replace your home launcher but gives you PIE navigation among other things, which comes down to this:

- <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

  [image: IMG:]
- You can set a PIE to Menu/Overview action from LMT app → PIE → select a PIE item → Menu
- Make sure you activate the LMT service from the Settings and then you can test the navigation.
- For starters, PIE can be navigated from left, right and bottom of the screen. Swipe from the edge towards the screen and you'll see the PIE.
- It has support for some limited gestures too. You would have to manually activate the feature from its Settings → Set Active Features.
- And don't tell anyone: it even has a PIE pointer.

  [image: IMG:]

Comment: Perhaps, [Pie Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jun.ace.piecontrol) would also work.

Comment: In case you're wondering about the current state of question and this answer, know that the answer was posted when  [revision 2](http://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/129729/2) was the current revision

Comment: sorry I can't find this app in google play store.

Comment: It's not in the Play Store. Click the heading of the answer. It has the link.

Comment: I saw links to apk files. I just don't install applications from untrusted or unknown sources.

Comment: I see. In that case, see if this comment here helps: [Enable software menu without virtual keys](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/161703)

Answer (score 1):

## [GMD GestureControl](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goodmooddroid.gesturecontrol)

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

The app has [Lite version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goodmooddroid.gesturecontroldemo)too. **Requires root access and not guaranteed to work on every device**.

As the name hints, you can control your device using gestures. You can choose to set a predefined gesture or you can create a custom one. The touch is supported for up to five fingers.

Anyhow, for our case, create a gesture, select number of points, and when selecting an action go to Action → Navigation → Menu. Exit the app and try your new gesture wherever an app has a menu. It should work.

Should you need any guidance in settings up the gesture, you can refer to my answer for [Unlock different Apps from lock screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/118943/96277)

Comment: In case you're wondering about the current state of question and this answer, know that the answer was posted when  [revision 2](http://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/129729/2) was the current revision

Answer (score 1):

## [All in one Gestures](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phoenixstudios.aiogestures)

Has in-app purchases and may **require root access**.

It helps you to control the phone using gestures. The gestures are divided into two categories: Hover and Swipe. Both categories have predefined edges such as top, right, left, bottom and more, and you  can configure the actions there.

For our case, the action is Menu and can be selected by ticking your desired edge under any of the category.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Comment: In case you're wondering about the current state of question and this answer, know that the answer was posted when  [revision 2](http://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/129729/2) was the current revision

Answer (score 1):

## [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)

Paid software, has 7 day free trial and **requires root access for our case.**

Tasker can create and show [scenes](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/scenes.html) in overlay blocking mode. What it means is, you won't have to dedicate specific part of the screen for the scenes and still can have virtual buttons.

Set the size of the scene to the size of the button you would want, assign an action to tap and show it using a task in overlay blocking mode. You can see the supplementary details in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120405/96277).

<sub>(Click image to enlarge; can you spot the alien here?)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Comment: In case you're wondering about the current state of question and this answer, know that the answer was posted when  [revision 2](http://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/129729/2) was the current revision

Answer (score 0):

## [GravityBox [JB]](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.gm2.gravitybox)

- For KitKat, Lollipop and Marshmallow: [GravityBox [KK]](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.kitkat.gravitybox), [GravityBox [LP]](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.lollipop.gravitybox), [GravityBox [MM]](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.marshmallow.gravitybox).
- Offers Pie controls, like [LMT Launcher](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/129733/96277) but  with very limited options.
- **Requires root access and [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)**.
- Per description, it should only be installed on a *stock AOSP Android ROM*.

Once the module is successfully enabled, go into GravityBox → Pie Controls → and configure the settings.

By limited options, I meant that you cannot remove a Pie but only change its action. In essence, it gives you a traditional navigation bar but with the ability to launch it using gestures from three edges of the screen  and customize the actions behind the keys. **Note** that you can always customize the color and size of your Pies.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Other apps with Pie navigation: [Pie Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jun.ace.piecontrol), [Handy Soft Keys](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ca.yesoft.handysoftkeys), [Floating Toucher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boatmob.floating.touch). Note that they are in the comments because I didn't or couldn't test them.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself.

Most of the suggested solutions require Xposed framework to be installed.

Unfortunately, Xposed installer warns about known critical issue with my ROM - [Aliyun OS](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=52289793&postcount=5).

Though I was not able to find how to enable 3dot menu button in applications (without navigation bar) I've found a suitable application duplicating required buttons.

It is [My Home Button](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wq.myhomebutton).

It is free, available in Google Play Store, no ad, but root is required for the menu option.

Go to `Settings->Floating buttons` and select `Floating buttons (root)` option.

After that, a floating button appears on the phone screen and expands with all buttons duplicating capacitive buttons functionality (home, back, recent apps and menu). In addition "home" and "recent" options appears in system shutter.

P.S. I still would like to enable 3dot menu in applications themselves.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]